# How to write .htaccess mod_rewrite rules for these cases?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Want to forward the following:

```
localhost/bla/index.html -> localhost/index.php?s=bla/index.html
localhost/blub.html -> localhost/index.php?s=blub.html
localhost/blog.html?site=10 -> localhost/index.php?s=blog.html&site=10
localhost/folder -> localhost/index.php?s=folder
```

but I only want do redirect .html and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$ [OR]
RewriteCond -d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Only if the uri ends with ".html" or if it's a folder, it rewrites the entire uri into the ?s= query string. The QSA flag should make sure that query strings on .html files (?site=10) are added to the new url as well.

Comment: very nice. thank you. how can i make this working with .html and .php also?

Comment: what if i want to use .php and .html (localhost/bla.php -> localhost/index.php?s=bla.php

Comment: change `.html$` in the first rule to `.(html|php)$`

Comment: i get a 500 server error :/ 
[Fri Dec 17 10:50:54 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '-d'